# passing value from one scene to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've looked it up and most of the information is on making a singleton class. I just want to pass one value to my helloworldlayer.m from my menuscreen.m. What is the easy way to do this.

```
- (void) changeScenePlay
{
   CCScene *testscene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];

    testscene.number = 1;

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:testscene];
}
```

One of the methods i have tried is something like this, but this isnt working for me either.

how do i access a variable in a scene and change it.

Comment: testscene.number = 1; this line is answering ur question

Comment: read this: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Strategies+for+Accessing+Other+Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable member in HelloWorld layer class.

```
    @interface HelloWorldLayer: CCLayer
    {
         int number;
    }
    @property(nonautomatic, assign) int number;
    @end

    @implementation HelloWorldLayer
    @synthesize number;

   +(CCScene *) sceneWithNumber:(int)inNumber
    {
        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

         HelloWorldLayer *layer = [[[HelloWorldLayer  alloc] initWithId:inNumber] autorelease];

        [scene addChild: layer z:Z_SCENE tag:TAG_SCENE];

        return scene;
    }

-(id) initWithId:(int)inNumber
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        self.number= inNumber;
    }
    return self;
}

    @end
```

Call sceneWithNumber instead of scene

```
- (void) changeScenePlay
{
    CCScene *testscene = [HelloWorldLayer sceneWithNumber:1];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:testscene];
}
```

Comment: okay i got it to work somewhat, but how do i get layer.number and use it in my helloworld layer

Comment: in layer class its member...access it through self, self.number :)

Comment: Because when i try to use it, it is telling me its zero

Comment: only chance is...u r accessing it inside init method. Just write initWithId function and use it in that.

Comment: how do i use the initwithId function?

Comment: so i replace my -(id)init with -(id) initWithId:(int)inNumber. when i do this it stops everything for some reason

Comment: i tried having it separate, but i have no idea to use the id function

Comment: for me its working...ok..show me ur helloworld layer file. use http://pastebin.com

Comment: nevermind i figured it out, forgot to do this part 
HelloWorldLayer *layer = [[HelloWorldLayer  alloc] initWithId:inNumber];
thanks so much for helping, is there anyway to tip you for your help?

Comment: yes..u can give tips...just by reading : message passing in objective C classes...he he..happy Coding...Bye !!!!

Answer (score 1):

create extern variable for this and do as you are doing.